# Jagged shadow with custom toon shader

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

I'm trying to render (using EEVEE) a couple of objects with very simple toon shaders but I can't get the shadows right. I want hard shadows but right now they are all weird-shaped.

Here is what I currently have :

[image: Render]

My scene has only those two objects on top of a plane with a sun lamp.

[image: Scene]

The sun lamp is configured like this :

[image: lamp settings]

And My render properties are set like this :

[image: Render properties]

Here is my nodes for the objects material :

[image: Objects material]

And the nodes for the floor material :

[image: Floor material]

Does anyone have any idea of what is doing this?